# Golang: map to struct

Tags: dictionary, struct, go

For some reason (fixed-length data file parsing), I've got a map and I want the elements of the map being saved in a struct.

Let's say:

```
type Point struct {X, Y int}
point := make(map[string]int)

point["X"] = 15
point["Y"] = 13

p := Point{point} // doesn't work
```

How do I do that? Or have I taken the wrong path?

Comment: Your only option is `p := Point{point["X"], point["Y"])`. You can't convert a `map` to a `struct` implicitly.

Comment: Try https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cant have automatic mapping like this unless you're using the [`encoding`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/) package, but you can use the following way:

```
p := Point{X: point["X"], Y: point["Y"]}
```

Comment: If you need to do this for multiple types, you can almost certainly write a generic function using reflection: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

If the efficiency is not so important, you can marshal the map into JSON bytes and unmarshal it back to a struct.

```
import "encoding/json"

type Point struct {X, Y int}

point := make(map[string]int)
point["X"] = 15
point["Y"] = 13

bytes, err := json.Marshal(point)
var p Point
err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &p)
```

This maks the code easier to be modified when the struct contains a lot of fields.

Comment: Hence I disagree with this approach (slow) I disagree with downvoting this as well as it is a valid answer. +1